# Number of symbol delay in decoder

Tags: coding-theory, information-theory

There is a coding table like this:

- 0    for A
- 01   for B
- 011  for C
- 1110 for D.

I know this coding is uniquely decodable but not instantaneous since it's not a prefix code. For recognizing whether 0111 will become AD or something like B.. or C... decoder has to wait. If the next symbol is a 0 then it must be an AD. So is 4 number of symbol delay in this decoder?

Comment: It is a bit difficult to know without definitions and background to the problem. Also it can be good to spend time on doing a good layout as it will increase the chance of people looking at the problem. I can help you with that here as you seem to be new.